# Multiple .EXE Files - Chromedriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to scrape using Selenium but I needed the chromedriver.exe. I downloaded it from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable. But there were multiple .exe files and I do not know which one to use. Please also tell if there are any compatibility issues between chrome versions and drivers